# div scroll does not fire in Firefox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that on a scroll the jQuery event does not fire. I've tried it as below as well as `$(".assignments-my-overflow")`. It works fine in IE and similar code works in a stripped down example in Firefox, but there is something in the js or css included in our website that causes it not to work in Firefox. I am using twitter bootstrap 2.0.4 currently. I had looked for `preventDefault()` calls that might be blocking it but see nothing obvious. Is there an easier way to figure out why it's not working other than to keep eliminating bits and pieces of css/js/html one at a time which is a little tedious ?

```
<div id='assignments-my-overflow' style="height:<%=percent%>; overflow:auto">

...

$("div").on("scroll", function(){
   // alert('scroll');
   console.log("scroll");
   $(".combo-input").hide();
   $(".combo-input").show();       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/EvDL4/1/

```
$("div").on("scroll", function(){
   alert('scroll');
   $(".combo-input").hide();
   $(".combo-input").show();       
});
```

Comment: I finally realized it is working, I am not sure which div is scrolling, but selecting all divs solved the problem. I spent hours trying to figure out why the div I thought should be scrolling was not. Glad I can finally move on